# Python - how to multiply characters in string by number after character

Tags: python

Title, for example I want to make 'A3G3A' into 'AAAGGGA'.
I have this so far:

```
if any(i.isdigit() for i in string):
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        if string[i].isdigit():
             (i am lost after this)
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simplistic approach:

```
string = 'A3G3A'

expanded = ''

for character in string:
    if character.isdigit():
        expanded += expanded[-1] * (int(character) - 1)
    else:
        expanded += character

print(expanded)
```

OUTPUT: AAAGGGA

It assumes valid input.  It's limitation is that the repetition factor has to be a single digit, e.g. 2 - 9.  If we want repetition factors greater than 9, we have to do slightly more parsing of the string:

```
from itertools import groupby

groups = groupby('DA10G3ABC', str.isdigit)

expanded = []

for is_numeric, characters in groups:

    if is_numeric:
        expanded.append(expanded[-1] * (int(''.join(characters)) - 1))
    else:
        expanded.extend(characters)

print(''.join(expanded))
```

OUTPUT: DAAAAAAAAAAGGGABC

Comment: [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) - it will generate iterators containing {A,10,G,3,ABC} ? based on true/false flip of isdigit?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, yes but it will also include the result of `isdigit()` along with the iterators so you also know what you're looking at!  Conceptually, something like: `[(False, ['A']), (True, ['1', '0']), (False, ['G']), (True, ['3']), (False, ['A', 'B', 'C'])]`

Comment: It is "better" to create an empty list where you add text and then glue it together with join, as your solution keeps creating new variables (+= with strings). I took the liberty and made edits +1.

Comment: @AntonvBR, you broke my code please rollback your edit!  Consider the string 'ABC3' which goes to 'ABCCC' but in your mod it goest to 'ABCABCABC'.  It was just an example, it didn't need added efficiency.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Adding a -1 does the trick. Do you want me to roll it back?

Comment: @AntonvBR, no, I've an alternative fix.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the format is always a letter followed by an integer, with the last integer possibly missing:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> s = 'A3G3A'
>>> ''.join(c*int(i) for c, i in izip_longest(*[iter(s)]*2, fillvalue=1))
'AAAGGGA'
```

Assuming that the format can be any substring followed by an integer, with the integer possibly longer than one digit and the last integer possibly missing:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> import re
>>> s = 'AB10GY3ABC'
>>> sp = re.split('(\d+)', s)
>>> ''.join(c*int(i) for c, i in izip_longest(*[iter(sp)]*2, fillvalue=1))
'ABABABABABABABABABABGYGYGYABC'
```

Answer (score 1):

A minimal pure python code which manage all cases.

```
output = ''
n = ''
c = ''
for x in input + 'a':
    if x.isdigit():
        n += x
    else:
        if n == '': 
            n = '1'
        output = output + c*int(n)
        n = ''
        c = x
```

with `input="WA5OUH2!10"`,   `output` is `WAAAAAOUHH!!!!!!!!!!`.
`+'a'` is to enforce the good behaviour at the end, because output is delayed.

Comment: Nice one, but I'd also use list [] for output, append and glue with join. And declaring variables on same row and not using row break for if statements creates lower readability in my opinion.

Comment: input is a builtin function, you should avoid using it as a variable name

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be -

```py
import re
input_string = 'A3G3A'
alphabets = re.findall('[A-Z]', input_string) # List of all alphabets - ['A', 'G', 'A']
digits = re.findall('[0-9]+', input_string) # List of all numbers - ['3', '3']
final_output = "".join([alphabets[i]*int(digits[i]) for i in range(0, len(alphabets)-1)]) + alphabets[-1] 
#  This expression repeats each letter by the number next to it ( Except for the last letter ), joins the list of strings into a single string, and appends the last character
#  final_output - 'AAAGGGA'
```

Explanation -

```
In [31]: alphabets # List of alphabets in the string
Out[31]: ['A', 'G', 'A']

In [32]: digits  # List of numbers in the string ( Including numbers more than one digit)
Out[32]: ['3', '3']

In [33]: list_of_strings = [alphabets[i]*int(digits[i]) for i in range(0, len(alphabets)-1)]  # List of strings after repetition

In [34]: list_of_strings
Out[34]: ['AAA', 'GGG']

In [35]: joined_string = "".join(list_of_strings) # Joined list of strings

In [36]: joined_string
Out[36]: 'AAAGGG'

In [38]: final_output = joined_string + input_string[-1] # Append last character of the string

In [39]: final_output
Out[39]: 'AAAGGGA'
```

Answer (score 0):

using the * to repeat the characters:

assumption repeater range between [1,9]

```
q = 'A3G3A'
try:
    int(q[-1]) # check if it ends with digit
except:
    q = q+'1' # repeat only once
"".join([list(q)[i]*int(list(q)[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(q),2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution. Assuming numbers in the range [0, 9].

```
>>> s = 'A3G3A'
>>> s = ''.join(s[i] if not s[i].isdigit() else s[i-1]*(int(s[i])-1) for i in range(0, len(s)))
>>> print(s)
AAAGGGA
```

Answer (score 0):

Embrace regex! This finds all occurrences of the pattern `non-digit character followed by non-negative integer (any number of digits)` and replaces that substring with that many of the character.

```
import re
re.sub(r'(\D)(\d+)', lambda m: m.group(1) * int(m.group(2)), 'A3G3A')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by numpy:

```
import numpy as np

x = 'A3G3A'

if not x[-1].isdigit():
    x += '1'

letters = list(x[::2])
times = list(map(int,x[1::2]))
lst = ''.join(np.repeat(letters, times))

#output
'AAAGGGA'
```